# Can we generate WSDL file in Java which accepts 2-dimensional array as parameter?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, apache-axis

I just want to know, if we can generate WSDL file which accepts 2-dimensional array as Parameter. Because, I tried to create WSDL file using Apache Axis2(bottom up approach) based on Java class but it shows the type="ns:ArrayOfString" in the WSDL file.